# Are there any direct international flights to Makhachkala, Russia (Makhachkala Uytash Airport) from anywhere?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, mcx

Are there any direct international flights to Makhachkala, Russia (Makhachkala Uytash Airport) from anywhere but ideally from Asia?

I tried the airport website but there are timetables only for -2 days to +2 days from today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uytash_Airport) shows that SCAT Airlines flies from MCX to Aktau, Kazakhstan, which technically is in Asia (despite being only 300 km away, it's on the other side of the Caspian Sea).  These flights didn't seem to show up on Kayak, but it may be that SCAT doesn't sell tickets through Kayak.

All the other flights listed are within Russia.

Comment: DV837 only flies on Mondays. And it seems to be the only flight meeting the criteria given... Best bet is to book it directly from SCAT.